# How to stream audio live from browser to shoutcast-server

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-audio, audio-streaming, shoutcast

I am able to record audio direct in the browser from the device-microphone. I am using for this HTML5 (audio-tag) and JavaScript (.getUserMedia). Now I am looking for the best way to stream it live to my shoutcast-server. I found several threads to this topic but they are all >5 years old and do not really solve my problem.

What is the best way to to stream audio live from the browser to a shoutcast server?

Answer (score 0):

The SHOUTcast source protocol is non-standard and cannot be streamed to directly from a browser.  Some sort of translating proxy is required.

It's also likely that this proxy will need to transcode the audio as well, as the codecs available to you in-browser are not typically used in SHOUTcast streams.